# What the gray area in the plane $x + y + z = 1$ means?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying *Solving Systems of Linear Equations* (*Fraleigh - Linear Algebra*), and I'm wondering for the meaning of the grayed are which appears in the following image:

[image: The plane x + y + z = 1]

The author adds:

*We know that a single linear equation in two unknowns has a line in the the plane as its solution set. Similarly, a single linear equation in three unknowns has a plane in space as its solution set.*

What is its analytical and geometrical interpretation of that grayed rhombus?

Comment: There is none: It's just a (necessarily) finite representation of an infinitely large object.

Comment: The area is representing the plane itself.

Comment: its a plane sort of infinite rectangle

Comment: The triangle drawn is part of the plane lying in the positive $x,y,z$ region while the gray area is just showing more of the plane.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: what you say is that plane is all of the infinite combinations of $x$, $y$, and $z$ which make the equation true (i.e., equal to 1)?

Comment: @Daniel, which is the purpose of "rest of the plane" representation?

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez to show that the plane extends beyond the triangle.

Comment: Think of the gray area as a sheet of paper that has 0 depth but also has inifinte length and width that is 'resting' on the quarter pyramid drawn.

Comment: Do not forget to vote and/ or accept the best answer, as it seems that you haven't done this for your previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

The expression 
\begin{equation}
x + y + z = 1
\end{equation}
is just a short way to say
\begin{equation}
\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x + y + z = 1 \}.
\end{equation}
You can also think this plane in the following way. Let $\langle$ , $\rangle$ denotes the standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^3$
\begin{align}
\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x + y + z = 1 \} &= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \langle(x,y,z),(1,1,1)\rangle = 1 \}\\
&= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \langle(x-1,y,z),(1,1,1)\rangle = 0 \}\\
&= \{(x,y,z) +(1,0,0): (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \text{ and } \langle(x,y,z),(1,1,1)\rangle = 0 \}.
\end{align}
In other words your plane is the plane of the vectors which are normal to the vector $(1,1,1)$, translated by $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: The fact that you're putting the $1$ next to the $x-$coordinate is a bit arbitrary, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, in fact you can write the affine space $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x + y + z = 1 \}$ as $S = V + v$ where $V$ is the vector sub-space $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x + y + z = 0 \}$ and $v$ is an arbitrary element of $S$. I choose $v = (1, 0 ,0)$ but I could have chosen something else, for example $v = (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$.